# Lie bracket of End(E)-valued differential forms

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms, vector-bundles

I have a question regarding the alleged Lie algebra structure for $End(E)$-valued differential forms. In Well's book *Differential analysis on complex manifolds*, Chapter III, the following definition of the "Lie bracket" of $\alpha\in\Omega^p(M,End(E))$ and $\beta\in \Omega^q(M,End(E))$: choose a frame $f$ for $E$ and consider the naturally induced frame in $End(E)\simeq E\otimes E^*$.

Identify $\alpha \equiv \alpha(f)$ meaning $\alpha(f)$ is a matrix of p-forms and $\beta(f)$ is a matrix of q-forms. Then one defined the value of $[\alpha,\beta](f)$ as the matrix formed by
$$
[\alpha,\beta](f) := \alpha(f)\wedge \beta(f) - (-1)^{pq}\beta(f)\wedge \alpha(f).
$$
Here $\alpha(f)\wedge\beta(f)$ is to be interpreted as the matrix of $(p+q)$-forms with ($i,j)$ element given by $\sum_k \alpha(f)^i_{~k} \wedge\beta(f)^k_{~j}$. Wells claims that this defines a Lie algebra structure in
$$
\Omega^*(M,End(E)) = \sum_{m\geq 0} \Omega^m(M,End(E)).
$$
However, I think this claim is false since this Lie bracket fails to be skew-symmetric. Certainly
$$
[\beta,\alpha](f) = (-1)^{pq+1} [\alpha,\beta](f) \neq - [\alpha,\beta](f)
$$
I understand that, however, this is the natural structure to be given on $\Omega^*(M,End(E))$ which showcases a particular relation to Lie algebra valued forms. I have also seen this bracket written differently as $[\alpha\wedge\beta]$ to indicate that one is "commuting" the endomorphisms as well.

[This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3904363/meaning-of-b2-for-b-in-omegam-operatornameende) particular question enlightens some of my concerns but doesn't quite address the issue of being a proper Lie bracket.

**Edit**: corrected wrong exponent $(-1)^{p+q}\rightarrow (-1)^{pq}$ in definition.

Comment: Don't local Lie algebra-valued forms like this have the structure of a [Lie superalgebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_superalgebra) rather than a Lie algebra?

Comment: In Loring Tu's *Differential Geometry: Connections, Curvature, and Characteristic Classes*, he makes a remark (Section 21.10) on this. Though I think the sign might need to be $(-1)^{pq+1}$ instead of $(-1)^{p+q+1}$.

Comment: I've looked up Tiu's book but he only comments Lie algebra valued  differential forms. As you say, the sign should be $(-1)^{pq}$ in the definition in order to turn this into a Lie superalgebra. Do you know any references that explains some further details in End(E)-valued differential forms? @ElliotYu

Answer (score 1):

I think you're right. Look up
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graded_Lie_algebra#Graded_Lie_superalgebras
and by your computation you have such an algebra